# How to get difference between two dates?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the difference between two dates?

I have:

```
date1 = 2014/2/20
date2 = 2014/2/16
```

I want to get the difference value as `4`.

Comment: Please read here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Formatting date has nothing to with jQuery.

Comment: what has jquery to do with this? I don't really understand. this is simply a manipulation of the Date object.

Comment: who even said query ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/r8Sds/)</kbd>

```
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;    
function getDateDiffinDays(d1, d2) {
    var firstDate = new Date(d1);
    var secondDate = new Date(d2);
    return Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
}

alert(getDateDiffinDays('2014/2/20', '2014/2/16'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get the difference in terms of number of days

```
var date1= "2014/2/20";
var date2= "2014/2/16";

var difference = (new Date(date1) - new Date(date2))/(1000*60*60*24);
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yEBL/)**

Comment: This solutions is also a great solution that would return the difference in days.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply get the day month and year from the date using js methods as getMonth,year etc.
after this you can sinply subtract.